# my App not running on my phone?

Tags: android

made an app. smoothly running on moto phone but not running on mi phones.

> Installation failed with message Failed to establish session.
>
> Error while Installing APKs

what i done:
enabled developer option.
enabled install Apks via USB.

is there any possible reason why this is happening?

Comment: Is there enough space in the phone, does it have a version of android that is high enough for the app, is the cable good? (Sometime a bad cable can cause errors like that, as ridiculous as it seems)

Comment: thanks but i factory reseted my phone yesterday. using moto data cable(file transfer going good),  android 6.0 in mi phone, ran this application in my moto phone(android 7.0).

Comment: Can you confirm that your app does not require Android 7? And that data transfer is enabled in the mi phone. Sometimes some phone will block data transfer (and show a notification that offer to activate it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem, please disable `Instant Run`

```
File-> Settings-> Build,Execution,Deployment-> Instant Run-> Uncheck (Enable Instant Run to hot swap code)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because for few reasons:

1. No enought space, but it should have told you so.
2. The minApi that your app supports is higher than the device's API.
3. Your app supports different processor architecture than your device.